# Google Cloud default network not found error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When first starting, I created a network called `my_network` and in trying to setup the firewall I'm getting the following error:

```
The resource 'projects/[my-project-name]/global/networks/default' was not found
```

when I run:

```
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-internal --allow tcp:1-65535,udp:1-65535,icmp
```

So, it seems there's no such thing as the `default` network?  I have a network that was created as `my_network` and it seems everything (i.e. new instances, routes) is attached to that. I'd like to restore the internal firewall rules, but without opening it up to the world. What is the best way to go about that?  Is there a "return to default" command? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using `my_network` just an example  for your question, since underscore can not be used in name of GCE network.

Having said that, in your command use `--network my-network` to create the firewall rules in `my-network` network. Omitting `--network` flag will cause command tries to create firewall rules on `default` network. This is described in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create) and some examples can be found in [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking).

About your other question, at the moment there is no "return to default" feature for firewall rules but you can use the following command to create `default-allow-internal` firewall rule for your network:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-internal --network my-network --allow icmp,udp,tcp --source-range 10.240.0.0/16
```

Replace `10.240.0.0/16` with IP range of your internal network.